# How to pick up a number from array with given probabilities

Tags: matlab

I have two numbers 1,2 with probabilities .7 and ,3 respectively. How can I pick up one number according to the given probabilities..

Comment: What have you tried until now? Do you have any specific problem? Moreover, you should look up "Bernoulli distribution" on Wikipedia, this should help you.

Comment: I tried but did not success.. how can I use bernoulli process to pick up a number..

Answer (score 4):

**Direct Implementation**

What you need is a scaled Bernoulli random number generator. The original Bernoulli random variable is 0 or 1, and you need 1 or 2. So the following code should work:

```
a = binornd(1,0.3)+1;
```

The first argument is the dimension (here 1, see MATLAB documentation), the second one is the probability of getting 1. By adding 1 this becomes the probability of obtaining 2.

***WARNING: The rest of the answer is not recommended for humorless people.***

**Geeky Implementation**

You can use the uniform random generator and tweak it:

```
a = rand; %in (0,1) range
result = 1*(a<=0.7) + 2*(a>0.7);
```

A cleaner way (thanks to Luis Mendo):

```
result = 1 + (rand>.7);
```

**Über-Geeky implementation**

Assuming some digit of the fractional part in `tic...toc` is uniformly random:

```
tic
A = rand(12060, 4400);
B = rand(12000, 4430);
t=toc;
t=round(t*10^3);
t = mod(t, 10);
randVal = (t<=6)*1 + (t>6)*2;
```

**Extended Über-Geeky Implementation**

Extending the previous approach, but this time using a pseudo-randomly generated 32-bit number (each bit being generated as in the previous method), dividing it by the maximum value, thus obtaining an approximately uniformly distributed variable between 0 and 1.

```
randNum = 0;
for i=0:31
   tic
   A = rand(12000, 4400);
   B = rand(12000, 4400);
   t=toc;
   t=round(t*10^3);
   randNum = randNum + mod(t,2)*2^i;
end
%randNum is a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 2^32 - 1

randNum = randNum/(2^32);

final = (randNum<=0.7)*1 + (randNum>0.7)*2;
```

Comment: Pure raw awesomeness. +1.

Comment: I usually don't upvote answers to poor questions but this one I couldn't pass, good work.

Comment: @runDOSrun - I usually don't either, but if the answer is really good and if person who wrote the answer showed a lot of effort and also clarified some confusing parts of the question, they certainly get my upvote.

Comment: Possibly faster (and cleaner): `result = 1 + (rand>.7);`

Comment: You might have noticed efficiency is not the principal criterion, but cleanness definitely is :) I will incorporate it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem of picking a number given a certain distribution is pretty common. Your example is a very simple form of that, although your question title implies you're interested in a generic solution.

Here is a simple function that works by selecting a random number from 0 to 1. It then loops through the values in the distribution array, accumulating them to from the cdf of the distribution. Once the value in the accumulator exceeds the random value, the index is returned.

```
function idx = randWithDist(dist)
    r = rand;
    a = 0;
    idx = 0;
    while(r > a)
        idx = idx + 1;
        a = a + dist(idx);
    end
end
```

It's overkill for your 2-value example, but you would use it like this: `randWithDist([.7 .3])`

If you are using this to select values from an arbitrary array (like your subject implies), simply use the returned value as an index to the array:

```
dist = [.2 .3 .4 .1];
val = [1 2 10 11];

samples = [];
for i=1:10000
    samples = [samples val(randWithDist(dist))];
end

histogram(samples);
```

This should pick 1 with .2 probability, 2 with .3, 10 with .4 and 11 with .1. The histogram plot shows that it seems to be working properly.

[image: histogram plot from above code]

The other tweak I would make to it in order to allow it to handle more generic inputs is changing the first line to `r = rand * sum(dist)`. This automatically normalizes the distribution so it doesn't have to sum to 1.